# Волатильные переменные

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть такая инициализация поля класса

```
if (thread == null) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this, getClass().getName());
            thread.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. вначале без всяких блокировок проверяем проинициализированно поле или нет. Если нет, тогда входим в критическую секцию, проверяем еще раз (на тот случай, если поле уже успело проинициализироваться) и создаем объект.

Вопрос, нужно ли поле `thread` объявлять с модификатором `volatile`? Все модификации этого поля идут внутри блоков `synchronized(this)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271/Ключевое-слово-volatile-в-java

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Это понятно. Но есть у меня подозрение, что использование synchronized приводит к тому, что я всегда буду иметь реальное значение

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552306/java-оператор-synchronized
Непонятно причем тут volatile =) спросили бы про synchronized, дал бы сразу на него ссылку =)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ответ по ссылке неправильный.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov во-первых, никаких копий нет. Во-вторых, [volatile и synchronized решают не только проблему с видимостью разных значений в разных потоках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811105/204271).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо. Именно то, что я хотел увидеть

Comment: Кстати, в вашем примере дизайн паттерн, называемый "double lock checking", но работает он только в том случае, если переменная volatile.

Comment: @aleshka-batman я уже понял

Comment: Можно и не волатайл. Но нужна другая переменная класса волатайл, которая будет вытаскивать все переменные класса из оперативки. То есть thread обычная переменная, а вот какойто ."volatile boolean monitor". В блоке синхрогизации ставим monitor *=-1, чтобы компилятор строчку не сьел, и после этой строчки thread будет равен тому что в оперативке. Во всяком случае должен. Я не пробовал лично)